# Can organizational trainings (Classroom and Web-based) be considered for Continuing Certification Requirements (CCR) of PMP?

Tags: pmp, certification, pmi-framework, pdu

Can organizational trainings on Project Management (Classroom and Web-based) be considered for Continuing Certification Requirements (CCR) of PMP?

For example I recently attended a few trainings on Leadership (classroom training), Agile Methods (classroom training), Organization specific Processes for Project Management  (classroom training), Estimation techniques (web-based training).

Can I report these as PDU's for PMI’s CCR? If yes, should these be reported under "Course or Training" or "Informal Learning"

Note: I read through the CCR handbook at http://www.pmi.org/-/media/pmi/documents/public/pdf/certifications/ccr-certification-requirements-handbook.pdf however it was not clearly mentioned whether organizational trainings can be considered or not.

Comment: This question should be asked of PMI; no answer you get here is authoritative.  That said, I would (and have) submitted all training in good faith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load any and all types of training you receive during your three years as it relates to project management and be as descriptive as you can in the tool.  For example, I believe the tools asks you for the provider of the training and you would enter the organization's name.  Allow PMI to either accept or reject the credit hours and go on from there.  You will either receive an immediate acceptance or rejection or it will tell you the credits are pending.